# Bootstrap modals appears only first time the second time appears only for few seconds

Tags: jquery

Bootstrap modals appears only first time the second time appears then closes. Why does it close automatically within a second?

```
// call this function on html tag onclick event and take parameter
function valuepass(a){
    b = a;
}
//on submit call this function
$("#submit_email").click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    email_name    = $("#email_name").val();
    email_add     = $("#email_add").val();
    contact_num   = $("#contact_num").val();
    email_message = $("#email_message").val();
    //send ajax requset to send_email.php
    $.ajax({url:"send_email.php",data:{name:email_name,email:email_add,contact:contact_num,message:email_message,user_id:b},success: function(ajaxresult){
$("#ajaxrequest_register").html(ajaxresult);
aa=ajaxresult;
//on success result perform given below action

var cc='Message send successfully';
if(cc==aa)
{
    $('#ajaxrequest_register').addClass("alert alert-success");
    setInterval(function () {$('#exampleModal').modal('hide')}, 2000);

}
else
{
    $('#ajaxrequest_register').addClass("alert alert-danger");

}

}});
});
//});
```

Comment: I can't even see where the modal is opened for the first time...

Nevertheless it has to be something with your if statement. 

Additionally the `if(cc==aa){...}` seems a little hacky to me, can't you check this different?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

setInterval repeats every two seconds forever, so presumably the first one is still repeating and hiding your dialog when the second one is started. I think you mean setTimeout. However, even then you'd get interference if the second event happened within 2 seconds of the first - you'd want to hag onto the handle returned by setTimeout and cancel it (clearTimeout) if that happens.

Comment: frankieandshadow thnx issue has resolved from your answer thankyou so much